# Is that a permutation or a combination problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I have to create a process where people would be asked to do 3 faces out of 7 possible.

The idea is that fraudster will not be able to record a video of all possible combinations.

If I have 7 possible poses and I ask someone to do 3 (they will always do 3 poses) how many videos of 3 poses are possible to shoot?

My guess what this:

> 7*7*7

if I allow for repetitions, and

> 7!/3!

if don't.

Is that correct? Besides that is this problem a permutation or a combination problem and why?

Comment: is the order of the face-doing relevant?

Comment: @user190090 no, it is not relevant.

Comment: in your first attempt you are counting the order, so this doesn't work. Your second attempt doesn't work either, but I am not quite sure what you tried there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter at all and we don't allow repetitions, that means a video with {super happy, happy, and tired} face is the same video as {tired, happy and super happy} face then the answer is with $n=\#\{\text{overall faces}\}$ and $k=\#\{\text{faces we want to shoot in the film}\}$

$$
\#\{\text{videos can be made with three expressions out of seven}\}=\binom{n}{k}=\binom{7}{3}=\frac{7!}{4!3!}=35
$$

If we allow repetitions, then we have

\begin{align}
\#\{\text{videos can be made with three expressions out of seven}\}^*=\binom{n+k-1}{k}=&\binom{9}{3}\\=&\frac{9!}{6!3!}=84
\end{align}

For both cases I recommend the Wikipedia article on [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), which is very nicely written. Since you don't want to count the order, I would call this kind not a **permutational** but a **combinational** problem.

Although I must say, in a real world, I would count the order in this case- For me this makes a difference in which order the faces occur and you cannot simply change it unless you are doing some video editing.

Comment: if the order was relevant, what would the answer be?

Comment: order and repetition would lead to your first attempt, so $7*7*7$